# Number of solutions to $\sin^{-1}x + |x| = 1$ and friends

Tags: trigonometry

The problem:

> If 
>   $$\begin{align}
> \sin^{-1}x\;+\;|x| &\;=\;1 \quad \text{has} \quad n_1 \quad \text{solutions}\\ 
> \cos^{-1}x\;+\;|x| &\;=\;1 \quad \text{ ... } \quad n_2 \quad \text{...} \\
> \tan^{-1}x\;+\;|x| &\;=\;1 \quad \text{ ... } \quad n_3 \quad \text{...} \\
> \cot^{-1}x\;+\;|x| &\;=\;1 \quad \text{ ... } \quad n_4 \quad \text{...} \\
> \sec^{-1}x\;+\;|x| &\;=\;1 \quad \text{ ... } \quad n_5 \quad \text{...} \\
> \csc^{-1}x\;+\;|x| &\;=\;1 \quad \text{ ... } \quad n_6 \quad \text{...}
> \end{align}$$
>
> then
>   $$n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 + n_5 + n_6 = \text{???}$$

**The answer is 6**, so the problem amounts to showing that each of the above has one solution each.

I started out with sine inverse; as modulus is always positive, $1-\sin^{-1}x \ge 0$, or $\pi/2 \ge x$. I don't see how to limit this to only one solution. I don't think that it is a matter of finding a common domain, as the equations are independent.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!! (I'd prefer a non-graphical approach; I'm not too fond of graphs.)

Comment: I get $7$.  One each for arcsine and arccosine, two for arctangent, and one each for arccotangent, arcsecant, and arccosecant.

Comment: @EricTowers The answer is 6...could you tell me how you arrived at the answer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of solution is pretty much the same for each of these.  As I noted in my comment, the "interesting one" is the arctangent equation, so I'll demonstrate that one.

To deal with the absolute value, we break into three cases:

- $x = 0$: $\arctan(0) + |0| = 0 \neq 1$.  So this is not a solution.
- $x > 0$:  Then $|x| = x$ and we tackle $\arctan(x) + x  = 1$.  At $x=0$, the left-hand side is $0$ and both summands increase monotonically and continuously as $x$ increases and their sum increases monotonically and without bound.  Consequently, there is exactly one $x>0$ satisfying the equation.  By calculator, $\arctan(\pi/6) + \pi/6 = 1.00595\dots$, so this $x$ is just less than $\pi/6$.
- $x < 0$:  Then $|x| = -x$ and we tackle $\arctan(x) - x = 1$.  The same monotonicity and increasing observations apply.  $\arctan(-2\pi/3) + 2\pi/3 = 0.969056\dots$, so this $x$ is just less than $-2\pi/3$.

For arccosine and arcsecant, the solution is "obvious" and the other choice for $x$ always gives sums that are too big.  Arccotangent goes as above, but for $x>0$, the sum is always too big.  For arccosecant, for $x>0$ the sum is always too big (but not monotonically increasing).  Otherwise, what you need to be looking at follows the pattern above.

I know you don't like graphing, but it might be useful for arcsine to plot the first quadrant of the unit circle.  Each point on that circle has coordinates $(x,y)$ and an associated angle, $\theta$, where $\sin^{-1}y = \theta$.  Plotting the points $(x,y+\theta)$ (which all lie above or on the circle) will give you a (distorted and left-right flipped) idea of what the graph of $\theta + \sin^{-1}\theta$ looks like.  You'll see that for $y=0$ (the far right), the sum is zero and increases as $y$ increases (moving to the left) increasing constantly to $1 + \pi/2 > 2.5$ at $y = 1$ (the far left).

Since at least one CAS claims no solution for the arccotangent equation, a table of approximate solutions:

- arcsine:  0.489...
- arccosine: 1
- arctangent: -2.132..., 0.520...
- arccotangent: -1.567...
- arcsecant: 1
- arccosecant: -1.651...

So, yeah, seven solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eric Towers !!! maybe that's a misprint or something in the book; the answer seems pretty satisfactory.